# Style Listbox so it just looks like an image (WPF XAML)

Tags: wpf, listbox

I realise this is a strange question but there is a method to the madness. I'm using a framework which makes dragging and dropping between ListBoxes seamless, and by implementing the interfaces I'll be able to achieve my desired outcome quite easily.

So what I have is a Listbox (lets call it ListBox B), and I want to be able to drag it to ListBox C. Now this is fine, but I don't want Listbox C to look like a Listbox - I just want it to be an image.

So basically I want my 30x30px image to act like a listbox. The actual items collection will all be handled internally, just for intuitiveness for the user I want them to be able to drag an item from ListBox B onto the image (ListBox C).

Again, there's no issue with the way the drag and drop behaves or how the listboxes behave - it's simply a style question.

How can I style a Listbox so it doesn't look like a Listbox at all - so it is just an image (which will be packaged in the application)?

Thanks

Comment: Try placing an `Image` on top of the actual `ListBox` and set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` on the `Image`. This should allow your drag and drop functionality to work whilst covering the visual appearance of the `ListBox` with an `Image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood Correctly, what you need is this:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.Template>
      <ControlTemplate>
         <Image Source="YourImage.png"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

Edit:

I still don't understand your statement that

> The actual items collection will all be handled internally, just for
>   intuitiveness for the user I want them to be able to drag an item from
>   ListBox B onto the image (ListBox C).

Please clarify

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. There should be no problem extracting that out into a re-usable style (Static Resource?) should there?

Comment: You can put that into a static resource w/o problem

Comment: As for the clarification, the image will be a picture of a folder. In this application the ListBox B I mentioned will be a list of temporary items. I want it to be clear graphically to the user that if they want to store one of these items permanently they just need to drag it on to the folder. As I mentioned, the actual logic will all be done internally so there's no reason for the full listbox to be displayed - just the folder image is sufficient.

Comment: This is a very nice solution _if_ the `ListBox` still functions (dropping items on it has to work) with that template.

Comment: I will test it tomorrow - I'll definitely accept it if it works.

Comment: As odyss-jii predicted, the drag doesn't work any more but the styling was as I requested so I marked it as accepted.